# Add Border/Text to images created with PhotoViewGallery

Tags: flutter, photo-gallery

I'm using PhotoViewGallery.builder to show a list of photos. Now I want adding a border and text to the photos. My problem is, the builder of the PhotoViewGallery only accepts as return the widget PhotoViewGalleryPageOptions and within the class, there is no property for child, border, text, ...

Here you see a snippet of my code using the PhotoViewGallery

```dart
   final List<Boulder> boulder;
   ...

   body: Container(
      child: PhotoViewGallery.builder(
        itemCount: boulder.length,
        pageController: PageController(initialPage: index),
        scrollPhysics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return PhotoViewGalleryPageOptions(
            imageProvider: NetworkImage(boulder[index].image),
            initialScale: PhotoViewComputedScale.contained * 0.8,
            minScale: PhotoViewComputedScale.contained * 0.8,
          );
        },
      ),
    ),
```

Normally I would use a Container & BoxDecoration with a DecorationImage to solve this, but in that case, the Container can't be use in the builder: property. Do you have any suggestions how to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

I've found the solution. The class PhotoViewGalleryPageOptions can be used like this: PhotoViewGalleryPageOptions.customChild(...). To add the border and text, i used a Container with BoxDecoration and DecorationImage

```dart
builder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
      return PhotoViewGalleryPageOptions.customChild(
        child: Container(
          child: bShowName ? InfoText(boulder: boulder, index: index) : Spacer(),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
              border: Border.all(
                color: difficultyMap[boulder[index].difficulty],
                width: 2,
              ),
              image: DecorationImage(fit: BoxFit.cover, image: NetworkImage(boulder[index].image))),
        ),
        initialScale: PhotoViewComputedScale.contained * 0.8,
        minScale: PhotoViewComputedScale.contained * 0.8,
      );
    },
```